# Indent line to the right with CMD + ] in insert mode

Tags: key-bindings, macvim

This is a usual shortcut in other editors: indent the current line to the right with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

How can achieve this in MacVim without leaving the insert mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In insert mode you can indent the current line with <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd> and dedent with <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>. Refer to `:help i_ctrl-t`

Comment: And if OP wan'ts to use his old mapping he can use `inoremap <C-]> <C-T>` in his `vimrc` to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: However if you're thinking of also mapping `<C-[>` don't. `<C-[>` is unfortunately what Vim sees when `<ESC>` is pressed so if you remap that, you wouldn't be able to get out of insert mode. :P

Comment: The OP wants to map Cmd (on a mac) not Ctrl.

Comment: Bleh, I can never keep which key the Cmd key maps to on Windows straight. It's alt right? So it would be `<A-]>` or `<D-]>`.

Answer (score 2):

The rhs of that mapping is difficult because there's no easily reliable way to jump back to the right column.

Two backticks returns to the previous jump point, so that *might* work, although it's not behaving reliably for me at the moment.

```
inoremap <D-]> <Esc>>>``i
```

Alternatively, you could mark your current spot, but that mark stays in the same column, so once you indent, that column is no longer correct (it's off by whatever you have shiftwidth set to). If you *always* set tabstop and shiftwidth to the same thing (e.g. you *always* do 2 spaces), you could get around that with something like

```
inoremap <D-]> <Esc>ma>>`alla
```

You'd have a similar problem with `gi` (return to previous insert point) but even worse, because you'd actually be back in insert mode shiftwidth characters before where you want to be, so you'd have to have multiple `<Esc>`s.

I think a better solution is to properly configure your indenting and then you won't even need to do this. E.g. `:h autoindent`, `:h smartindent` and `:h cindent`

Note that these mappings won't work in terminal vim since Cmd is consumed by the terminal itself and not passed to vim.

EDIT:

Per @NathanWilson's response, this would work:

```
inoremap <D-]> <C-t>
inoremap <D-[> <C-d>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the correct answer is (as already mentioned)

```vim
inoremap <D-]> <C-t>
inoremap <D-[> <C-d>
```

Of course, you can define the `CMD+]` mappings also for normal and visual mode:

```vim
nnoremap <D-]> >>
nnoremap <D-[> >>
xnoremap <D-]> >
xnoremap <D-[> <
" If you prefer to keep the visual selection (not the vim way)
" xnoremap <D-]> >gv
" xnoremap <D-[> <gv
```

#### Default Mappings of Vim

However, note that vim already provides builtin mappings

```vim
CTRL-T
CTRL-D
```

which obviously work everywhere (Linux/Windows/MacOS, gui/cli, etc.).

Secondly, vim is a modal editor where many changes are meant to be done in *normal mode* and not in insert mode. I consider increasing or decreasing indentation a change most often done in normal mode. Vim provides mappings to change indentation in normal mode with

```vim
>> or >{motion} 
<< or <{motion}
```

Combing `>` or `<` with a *text-object* (`:h text-objects`) such as `ip` you can indent larger parts of text with a single command.

Another important vim feature here is the *dot-command* (`:h .`) to repeat it: `>ip..` means indent paragraph three times.

#### Transition to *Vim's Way*

I would use `CMD+][` mappings to ease your transition to vim. If you know the vim mappings by heart, you could or *should* consider removing them. `MacVim` provides other `CMD+` mappings which follow the macOS human interface guidelines (HIG) `:h macvim-shortcuts` (most importantly `CMD+s` for saving, `CMD+f` for finding, `CMD+b` for building and `CMD+x/c/v` for cut, copy, paste). However, in my experience when you have become familiar with vim, you do not need them anymore and use vim consistently between platforms. Even though I admit that `"+p` is not as convenient as `CMD+v`, but in this case IMHO `CTRL-t/d` are as good as `CMD-]/[`.

Comment: If you're just going to add a note, it should probably just be a comment.

Comment: Generally, I agree. However, I prefer to have all important information in answers not in comments or in addendums of answers which do not provide a short and consice answer. What do you think?